# react CSS flashing animation not working no limitly

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make flash animation on react but it's not working. The code that I have used is as below:

```
@-webkit-keyframes capulse {
    0% {
      background-image: url("../../../../../assets/img/decks/cameras/2/camera360Red.png");
      opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {

      background-image: url("../../../../../assets/img/decks/cameras/2/camera360Blue.png");
      opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
      background-image: url("../../../../../assets/img/decks/cameras/2/camera360Red.png");
      opacity: 1;
    }
}

.camera-icon-active {       
    width: 220%;      
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-animation: capulse 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: what is this! can u explain more your problem!

Comment: that is not working as unlimit

Answer (score 0):

You should add "infinite" at the animation value.

```
.camera-icon-active {       
width: 220%;      
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
-webkit-animation: capulse 1s infinite linear;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Okay That is good working

correct code is

```
  .camera-icon-active {       
    width: 220%;      
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-animation: capulse 1s infinite linear;
}
```